# How to make a object array available in different parts of the application?

Tags: jquery

I created a object array inside a click function like this:

```
    $(".tableButton").click(function()
    {
         CK.tableArray = ["test1","test2","test3","test3"]; // this works
         processTableInfo(CK.tableArray); // this works
    });
```

Now I need to access the CK.tableArray from another part of the application using the same array information from click function above. I need to access a different range of elements inside this array from above...

```
    $(".displayTable").click(function()
    {
        alert(CK.tableArray) // not define
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to park the variable underneath a global namespace, such as window.

```
$(".tableButton").click(function()
{
     window.tableArray = ["test1","test2","test3","test3"]; // this works
     processTableInfo(window.tableArray); // this works
});
```

Then access it through the global namespace:

```
$(".displayTable").click(function()
{
    alert(window.tableArray) // not define
})
```

In your example posted, it really depends on where CK is defined (the scope), however. For more information on this, you can visit the MDN article on [Functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

You can also checkout the MDN article [Scope Cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)

You can also checkout the following [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: you beat me by 2 sips of coffee :)

Comment: Still can't understand why the CK.tableArray does not work. The window.tableArray is working

Comment: Where is CK defined & initialized in your code relative to your "click" event listener? The answer to this question is why CK.tableArray does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to pass around `array` object only, try tacking it with `window` object.

```
window.tableArray = ["test1","test2",...]
```